# Loop through particular workbook (by path) and particular sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In excel file '`A.xlsx`' - I have a userform wherein on clicking the browse button (`CommandButton1`), another excel file is opened (say '`B.xlsx`)' and the names of the sheets present in the excelfile show up in 'Select Demand Plan' combobox (`ComboBox1`)

[image]

The code that does this is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Workbooks.Open (sFilePath)

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
          Form.ComboBox1.AddItem (sht.Name)
    Next sht
End Sub
```

I want that all the column headers ( column names) of the selected worksheet (Say `Sheet1`) in the selected workbook (`B.xlsx`) show up in the other Comboboxes (`Part Number, CSUFI/ATA, Keyword` ..)

I started writing a separate function for this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    cmb = Form.ComboBox1.Value
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(cmb).Range("A1:AR1")
        Form.ComboBox2.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox3.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox4.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox5.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox6.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox7.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox8.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox9.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox10.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox11.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox12.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox13.AddItem (Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Clearly, the problem with this code is that it loops through the current `ActiveWorkbook` which is A.xlsx. I want that it loops through the selected workbook (B.xlsx)

1. How does one do this?

Also, as of now I am giving it a hardcoded range (A1:AR1) which causes a lot of null entries in the combobox. Intent is that it loops through only the column headers that are not null ( valid Column Headers)

2. How should I do that?

The complete code as of now:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    cmb = Form.ComboBox1.Value
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(cmb).Range("A1:AR1")
        Form.ComboBox2.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox3.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox4.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox5.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox6.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox7.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox8.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox9.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox10.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox11.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox12.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        Form.ComboBox13.AddItem (Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Workbooks.Open (sFilePath)

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
          Form.ComboBox1.AddItem (sht.Name)
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: then do not use `activebook`, use `workbooks("B.xlsx")`

Comment: How? The path to the workbook is in `CommandButton1_Click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sFilePath As String
    sFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)

    For Each sht In wb.WorkSheets
          Form.ComboBox1.AddItem sht.Name
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Then in other methods you can use the global `wb` in place of ActiveWorkbook

For part 2:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim cmb, Cell As Range, rng As Range, sht As Worksheet

    cmb = Form.ComboBox1.Value

    Set sht = wb.Worksheets(cmb)
    'assuming your headers are always on the first row...
    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("A1"), _
                        sht.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    'add some code here to clear the lists first!...


    For Each Cell In rng.Cells
        If Len(Cell.Value)>0 Then
            Form.ComboBox2.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox3.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox4.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox5.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox6.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox7.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox8.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox9.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox10.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox11.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox12.AddItem (Cell.Value)
            Form.ComboBox13.AddItem (Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It gives me a `Type mismatch (Error 13) ` at `For Each Cell In Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(cmb).Range("A1:AR1")`

Sorry for being so same about these questions. VBA is just too over me. Is this error due to type casting?

Comment: `wb` is already a Workbook object, so it's just `For Each Cell In wb.Worksheets(cmb).Range("A1:AR1")`

Comment: Thanks! This worked. 
Can you also give pointers on how I should tackle the 2nd issue?